# Constant "Low on memory" crashes

Tags: galactic-civilizations-3

Whenever I play Galactic Civilizations 3 for more than 2 hours or so, the game just crashes with a "Low on memory" error.

The error message sounds quite clear. However, I currently have 16GB of DDR4 RAM, with a recommended requirement for the game of 6GB of RAM.

The fact that the longer I play, the worse it gets would lead me to believe that there is some serious memory leak, which makes the game use up all my RAM until there's nothing left to use.

So, can I limit the RAM usage for the game or any other way of preventing the massive increase in RAM usage when playing longer games?

Comment: Are you sure the ram is properly inserted ? You may think you have 2*8 GB but only one of them is working (To check go to My/Computer right click ->Properties)
Do you have other RAM consuming apps opened while playing. I'd sometimes get my games hungry for RAM when Chrome is opened with 15 tabs on the background ...

Comment: Yes, It's properly inserted and I've never had a problem with any other game, including some more demanding stuff. The first time it happened I had Firefox open, so I thought that was the culprit. But no, with everything closed, the game still starts slowing down and crashing on long play sessions (and it's a type of game that pretty much requires long play sessions). On my last try I only had the Radeon Control Center running in the background with no effect.

Comment: Is this something recent? Or has it been going on for longer? I've read someone else had similar problem since the new windows insider build

Comment: Anecdotally GalCiv3 uses a stupid amount of RAM for me also, Steam version recent install. From reading the forums 16GB _should_ be enough to run the largest map with maximum empires. So, unless it's patched the best solution is to shut the game down and reload the save file. You can also try decreasing the texture resolution which can help slightly.